# Pre-populating Google custom search field

Tags: jquery, search-engine

I have a Google custom search engine on my site. I want it so that a user can select values from a 2 select menus and the search engine text field would populate with the selected values.  The code given to me by Google is:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'specialassignedcxvalue';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

I was thinking that a jquery on('change', '#menu', function()) call would work and then call html() and pass the value, but I don't know where to write the value.  Any ideas??  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After more research there is no way to pre-populate the Google search element. They only allow you to send a search query via the GET /search.php?q=term from the end user. It also seems to be against their current TOS

1.3 Your Obligations. You shall receive a Query from the End User and shall forward that Query to Google.

https://www.google.com/cse/docs/tos.html

Comment: That TOS only says you can't modify the results. It says nothing about influencing the initial query.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I have a REALLY MESSY fix though...

Using a server side script (PHP for example below) you can add onto a "blank/empty" search results using the gsce attribute webSearchQueryAddition="". I would love if someone could tell me a proper way to do this all by Javascript/jQuery if possible. I think you might have to have a ?q=* just to trick the page into searching so you can add your pre-filled query into it.

```
 <gcse:searchresults webSearchQueryAddition="<?php echo 'preFilledQuery'; ?>"></gcse:searchresults>
```

More at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes

PS: I also tried using jQuery to append the attribute "webSearchQueryAddition" with a value to the `<gcse>` tag before it loaded, but it did not seem to work either